# should be a way to get the file's path easily?

Tags: python, filepath

for example,i have static files in static folder,the files relative path from root is

```
/static
```

root path is D:\proj\src

if i want to load the xml file,i should just give the relative path ,for example

```
/static/xml/a.xml.
```

i don't need to change the string ,add '../' or '../../' depend on where the module i was, that's was silly, so can you me give a better way only use standard libery?

project abs root path + relative path should be ok,but i tried and failed.

Comment: A path that starts with `/`, the directory separator, is generally *not* called "relative", in Unix terms that's an absolute path. The relative version of `/static` is simply `static`.

Comment: Are you using windows or linux? Because you talk about `/static`, `../` etc but then you say that the root directory is `D:\proj\src`.
Or maybe you have a data partition in common with the two Oses?

Comment: And what, exactly, did you try, and in what way did it fail?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a full path to a filename such as /static/xml/a.xml

You can then get to the different parts of it quite easily in python like this

```
import os
fullFilePathName = '/static/xml/a.xml'
#
# the filename
#
theFilename = os.path.basename(fullFilePathName)

#
# The path to the file
#
thePath = os.path.dirname(fullFilePathName)

#
# Join the two together to form a path
#
fullName = os.path.join(thePath, theFileName)
```